# Does Node Schedule spawn/fork new process

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Does node-schedule npm module spwan/fork new process or we have to do it ourself ?

```
var cron = require('node-schedule');
var cronExpress="0 * * * *";

 cron.scheduleJob(cronExpress, () => {
            //logger.info("Cron expression Rule "+Date());
            doSomething();
        });
```

Using the above piece of code will run the job on the same instance or spawn another process i.e node-schedule handles this?

Comment: It seems like it will only invoke the passed job function, see here: https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule/blob/master/lib/schedule.js#L175

Comment: Just by looking in the source-code I would say it runs on the same instance since there's no spawn or fork called. Also no `require('child_process');`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51496511/5222115[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51496511/5222115) Refer above answer

Answer (score 0):

```
cron.scheduleJob(cronExpress, () =>  {
   shell.exec(node ../jobs/job1.js');
});
```

You can use `ShellJS` or [childprocess](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) to do some stuff.